# How to include the named of the called contract in Event Log

Tags: solidity, events

in my code I am using events in order to log some date. I would like to include the name of the contracts I am calling out of my main contract into this event log. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible:

There is no way (yet) for a contract to read another contract's name. If you know the contracts you are calling, you can reference their name by some identifier, either a string or a number. Like

```
event contractCalled(uint256 indexed theContractsNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you could do a mapping in which you would register the name of the contract for its address :

`mapping(address => string) contractName;`

and then, use this mapping to put the name of the contract in the event

```
contract myContract{

    mapping(address => string) contractName;
    event myEvent(address contractRef);

    function myContract(){
        // constructor
        ...
    }

    myMethod(address _contract){
        ...
        myEvent(contractName[_contract]);
    }
}
```

Note however that you should have to populate yourself the mapping with the intended names you want.